# Firing rate of $(window).scroll event in mobile browser

Tags: jquery

I use `$(window).scroll()` event to add animations to my elements.

- In desktop browsers, the event is fired when mouse is **scrolling**.
- In mobile browsers, the event is fired when drag & touch has **ended**.

Is there any way to make the `scroll()` event fires when the touch is dragging (to scroll down/up) ?

Example code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  console.log('fired');
});
```

Last, here is a [demo page](http://dev.raptor.hk/scroll.html) (can't use JSFiddle well in mobile, thus I host it elsewhere). Please try it on Desktop & Mobile browsers. For your convenience, here is the QR code:

[image]

Comment: I kinda feel binding `touchmove` may help

Comment: @Alexander it won't help when we have momentum scrolling

Comment: @Dan, fair enough. Although, this question is not about momentum scrolling

Comment: @Alexander, the question is about monitoring scroll on mobile devices. Since most devices add inertia to their scrolling, it should definitely be taken into account. Imagine you track `touchend` event only, and after you get the touchend coordinates, the content still scrolls half screen down.

Comment: @Dan, But I have the impression you should alvways get correct values from the devices when asking for coordinates even if the scrolling have inertia or not

Comment: @Alexander yes, `touchmove` returns correct values but cannot replace `scroll` due to reasons listed above.

Comment: Because scrolling can continue long after `touchend`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been playing with catching scroll realtime on most popular browsers on mobile and touch devices for over a week!

I have tried many approaches like putting `setInterval` or `requestAnimationFrame` loop or catching `scroll` or `touchmove` or web workers or whatever. I can tell you that nothing works on iOS 4 - 7, the browser just freezes **any** script execution.   Browser for Android, mobile Chrome or Firefox or Dolphin track `scroll` well, so you can deal with momentum scrolling there. Latest internet explorer mobile, Blackberry, Opera mobile and most Symbian browsers track `scroll` as well.

There is a brilliant way to do things on iOS, however. This guy emulates scroll using CSS3 `transform: translateY`:  https://github.com/joehewitt/scrollability/blob/master/scrollability.js Actually, javascript/CSS fully emulate what iOS Safari does natively.

This works without any lags because of using GPU accelerations and has no restrictions. You can even change scroll parameters like friction or responsivity. The downside is that you need to serve another styles or markup for iOS only. You can use media queries or browser detection for this. Please find some demos online, because the author provides no clear documentation. Example: [stellar.js](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/demos/ios.html) iOS Paralax demo. There are some other examples available.

To track the current scroll position use something like this:

```
var page = document.getElementById('page'); 

var scrollTop = isIOS ?
    -(new WebKitCSSMatrix(getComputedStyle(page).webkitTransform)).m42 : 
    window.scrollY;
```

Fire this inside requestAnimationFrame loop. Unfortunately you can't fetch the scroll coordinates in a more elegant way than using `WebKitCSSMatrix` in this version of library. But you can make a pull request for this.

Hope this will work for you!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use this:

```
document.addEventListener("touchmove", touchScrollHandler, false);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? `touchScrollHandler` is not defined too. My question is about jQuery, not traditional JavaScript. Also, for `touchmove` event, how does it perform in desktop browser?

Comment: Sorry, I had assumed plain JavaScript would be okay, the touchScrollHandler is a plain function you define and will get an event, you could then calculate the scroll position by checking the scroll position of the page. Here's the a jQuery implementation that will make more sense to you: http://forrst.com/posts/jQuery_iPad_one_finger_scroll-B30

Comment: Tried `$('body').on('touchmove')`, it behaves the same as `scroll()`