# Sticky navigation issue with touch devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Have created a sticky menu, which is working fine for desktop and mobiles.

But there is a small issue with mobiles, when ever scrolling the page and the finger is still on the screen then 
after reaching to the position of the container where the menu needs to stick it is not happening.

When I removed the finger from the screen, then it is taking a second time and the menu is getting fixed.

is there any solution for this, kindly help me with a sample demo.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0wLmLtq6/4/)

JS:

```
var menuSection = $('.section') , navLists = $('.menu ul li'),
            navLists_height = navLists.outerHeight(), headerOffset = $('.top_layer').offset().top;

        $(window).on('scroll', function () {
            var window_top = $(window).scrollTop() + 12;
            if (window_top > headerOffset) {
                $('.menu').addClass('fixed');
            } else {
                $('.menu').removeClass('fixed');
            }
            var cur_position = $(this).scrollTop()+70;
            menuSection.each(function() {
                var top = $(this).offset().top - navLists_height,
                    bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();

                if (cur_position >= top && cur_position <= bottom) {
                    navLists.find('a').removeClass('active');
                    menuSection.removeClass('active');

                  $(this).addClass('active');
                  navLists.find('a[href="#'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').addClass('active');
                }
            });         
        });
    navLists.find('a').on('click', function () {
                  var $el = $(this)
                    , id = $el.attr('href');
                  $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(id).offset().top - navLists_height
                  }, 500);
                  return false;
            });
```

Comment: On some touch devices, scroll event is fired only once scroll is finished. Does it help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058228/firing-rate-of-window-scroll-event-in-mobile-browser  ?

Comment: @A. Wolff : I tried but not works